# Adding posts to a category

Tags: wordpress

My question is about `posts` and `category`. What is the right `php` template for adding posts to a category so that new posts would be displayed in order for a specific category?

So , I have single.php, I have `category.php`. Do I need `archive.php` as a must or no? 
For example, I want to put a category in my menu, then click to that category to view posts but even if I link new posts to that category, none are displayed. Indeed, I can view my posts individually but not if I go to a category page.
What should I do to figure out it right?

Comment: your question is too broad. add more information, like which code you tryed to use, provide them. also, before it try to read wordpress codex. you may find all answers you need

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

Answer (score 0):

what I did is put Category to my Custom Menu. Created category.php  and single.php . Then for category file I put
     `

```
get_header(); ?>


        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

  <header class="entry-header" style="padding-top:20%;">


 </header>
<div class="date"><?php the_date(); ?></div>
    <div class="author"><?php the_author(); ?></div>
  <div class="entry-content w3-hover-grey" style="height:100%; border: 
solid;  " >
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>

 </div><!-- .entry-content -->
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"> Показать больше...</a>

<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
<div class="nav-previous alignleft"><?php next_posts_link( 'Older posts' ); 
?></div>
<div class="nav-next alignright"><?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer posts' ); 
?></div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>`
```

This works for me , I can add posts to the category page. maybe not really right way to do so but it works for me.